# Installing vs 2015 - VSSetupUtility - package is either missing or damaged.

Tags: visual-studio-2013

Hi **David**  and othere my freinds. I'm trying to set up a server , I installed net frame work 3.5  and then I installed sqlServer 2014 enterprise ,office 2013 , the os system is server 2012, now I 'm installing vs 2015, i got an error page witch says :
A setup package is either missing or damaged. 
....
J:\packagees\vs_professional\VSSetupUtility
Iso file is in J drive  and I can see the file and size of this file is 218 kb
Is it correct? and what should I do, where can I get it
Best Regards , there isn't tag for visual-studio-2015 so I used 2013
Tomas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution to the problem in this article: [Create an Offline Installation of Visual Studio](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt706497.aspx). After running this command:

```
vs_enterprise.exe /layout D:\VisualStudio2015
```

I got a big installer (24 Gb) and I installed VisualStudio offline.